# How to login to wikipedia using mediawiki API through?

Tags: javascript, c#, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I already have two working bots in Wikipedia, but they use different method.
Currently, I am trying to create a bot using C#. On the API documentation page, they have provided some sample codes in java, PHP, and python. But unfortunately, they haven't provided any sample code in C#. It is the only language I am familiar with.

This is the [Wikimedia API:Edit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login) documentation page. Would someone kindly convert the few words from java (or any other language) to C#?

If I could get only this code converted to C#, I can build the rest of the bot by myself.
I asked help on the relevant noticeboard(s) on the wikimedia site(s), but nobody there is familiar with C#. That's why I am now asking this outside of wikipedia.

Thanks a lot in advance

This is the java source-code:

````js
```

/*
edit.js

MediaWiki API Demos
Demo of `Login` module: Sending post request to login

MIT license
*/

var request = require( 'request' ).defaults( { jar: true } ),
url = 'https://test.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';

// Step 1: GET request to fetch login token
function getLoginToken() {
var params = {
    action: 'query',
    meta: 'tokens',
    type: 'login',
    format: 'json'
};

request.get( { url: url, qs: params }, function ( error, res, body ) {
    var data;
    if ( error ) {
        return;
    }
    data = JSON.parse( body );
    loginRequest( data.query.tokens.logintoken );
} );
}

// Step 2: POST request to log in.
// Use of main account for login is not
// supported. Obtain credentials via Special:BotPasswords
// (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:BotPasswords) for lgname & lgpassword
function loginRequest( loginToken ) {
var params = {
    action: 'login',
    lgname: 'bot_username',
    lgpassword: 'bot_password',
    lgtoken: loginToken,
    format: 'json'
};

request.post( { url: url, form: params }, function ( error, res, body ) {
    if ( error ) {
        return;
    }
    console.log( body );
} );
}

// Start From Step 1
getLoginToken();
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't go so deeply but I hope you can take a look at this page and find out how to do it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
private static async Task LoginRequest(string loginToken)
{
    var data = new
    {
        action = "login",
        lgname = "bot_username",
        lgpassword = "bot_password",
        lgtoken = loginToken,
        format = "json"
    };
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(LOGIN_URL, data))
    {
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseString);
        Console.WriteLine(responseObject);
    }
}

private static async Task<string?> GetLoginToken()
{
    var url = $"{LOGIN_URL}?action=query&meta=tokens&type=login&format=json";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    {
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseString);
        return responseObject?["query"]?["tokens"]?["logintoken"]?.ToString();
    }
}
```

For converting the response you need

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

You can call these methods from your `Main` method like this:

```
const string LOGIN_URL = "https://test.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";

public static async Task Main()
{
    var loginToken = await GetLoginToken();
    await LoginRequest(loginToken ?? throw new Exception("No login token."));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tremendous help, but now I'm getting CS5001 error. "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point." I had "public static void Main()", then I tried "public void Main()". Still the same error.

Comment: @usernamekiran I updated the answer

Comment: Hi. The later suggestion didnt work either. So I created a new class at the top of the code, and tried to call the "public class botlogin" from it (rest of the entire code was in "public class botlogin"). I still got the same error. I think I should give up on this for now, and come back to it after 7-8 months from now. Thanks for your help again.